# Retrieve Custom Journey Builder Name When Journey Executing

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, node.js

I am developing Custom Journey builder activity(using node application)
i want to get journey name when journey execution time.

**note:**
Previously i am getting current executing journey version using
{{Context.VersionNumber}} this data binding code.. now i want to get executing journey name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `connection.trigger('requestInteraction')` Postmonger event to retrieve the entire WDF JSON payload, which includes the Journey name.